# Javascript Click.function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to javascript but now I need to make a navigation with javascript . The navigation is supposed to look like that. 
http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3332/rp9cuury_jpg.htm

If you click on "Home", the home "button" should move to the right a bit. Then when you click on the "About me" button the Home button should go back and the About me button moves to the right...and so on with the rest of the navigation. Everytime you click on a button it should move to the right and as soon as you click another button it should go back and this button goes to the right.

I didn't put the right px numbers yet, but I already build a javascript code for it and it's causing me problems. When I click on "Home" the footer div (the black bar at the bottom) is moving instead of the home div. And I have no idea how to fix that. As soon as I delete the footer div completely, nothing is happening at all when I click on it. 
Maybe someone can help me with that?

I don't know if you need the CSS code as well but so far here's the javascript and the html code.

```
$(window).load(einblenden);

function einblenden(){
$("#navi_home").click(moving1); 
}

function moving1(){
$("div").animate({"right":"500px"},300);
$("#navi_home").animate({"right":"200px"},300);
inhalt(1); }


function inhalt(nr){
$("#inhalt").load("seite"+nr+".html", function(){ $(this).fadeOut(0).fadeIn(600);});
}
```

And the html

```
  <div id="wrapper">

  <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div> <!-- End Logo -->

    <div id="navi_home">Home</div>
    <div id="navi_about">About me</div>
    <div id="navi_portfolio">Portfolio</div>
    <div id="navi_contact">Contact</div>


    <div class="clear"></div> 

<div id="content">

  <p id="inhalt"> </p>

  </div> <!-- End Content -->

<div id="footer">

  </div> <!-- End Footer -->

   </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
```

Comment: I suspect your $("div") selector is what's causing you problems. What happens if in moving1() you just have $("navi)home").animate()?

Comment: @wendelbsilva: The $("#navi_home").click(moving1); is already part of it. So when I want the click to happen where exactly do I put the settings for the animation (like making it going to the right 200px?) 
         $("navi_home").click({"right":"200px"},300); ?

Comment: @JoshuaBrodie Even though I think it's the $(div) as well, I already tried to remove it but then nothing happens at all.

Comment: Keep the code clarity for next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBFaD/). Adding a nav-button class to each button in the html will make it easier to apply the behavior to all of them. I also switched out your `$(window).load()` for `$(function () {})`, which is an alias of `$(document).ready()`. I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with `$("div")`, but this code just animates the left margin of any nav-button when clicked:

```
$(function () { 
    einblenden();
});

function einblenden() {
    $(".nav-button").click(function() {
        $(".nav-button").animate({"margin-left":0},300);
        $(this).animate({"margin-left":200},300);
        inhalt(1);
    });
}

function inhalt(nr) {
    $("#inhalt").load("seite"+nr+".html", function(){ $(this).fadeOut(0).fadeIn(600);});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it's at least doing something which helps a lot. But it's still not doing what it should be doing. Like you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/nsZH7/ 

What exactly I want for my navigation is that when you click on "Home", the Home button goes to the right. When you click on "About me", the Home button goes back and the About me button pushs to the right...and so on.

Comment: [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/tBFaD/2/). Your html seems to have some funky formatting that the animations are messing up. I can try and get it working on yours if you like, but it will take more time.

Comment: Yes, exactly like it should look like. Still not really working the right way with my file, though. 
But the javascript looks already way easier to understand. Could I still add a different 'function inhalt' (it's the content that comes with clicking the button.) Or are all of them just going to open with 'inhalt(1)' now? 
But it would be really great if you could help me out with making it work for me. And I'd be really thankful.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/nsZH7/2/. Right now they will all load the same page, but it's not tough to get working. I would suggest adding a `data-page="yourPage.html"` attribute to each nav button and then passing that value to inhalt like `inhalt($(this).attr('data-page'))` when the button is clicked. That said, there are many other ways to navigate dynamic content and you might want to check around SO or find a tutorial.

Comment: Wow it actually works. Thank you so much for your help. It's surprising to see you made a list out of the navigation, because that's exactly how I started, until I changed it to single divs. But looking at what you changed, everything finally makes sense to me. I usually have to look at something "finished" once (and I couldn't find a tutorial for this navigation), to find out how to do it and how everything works and I'm really thankful that you took your time to help me out with it. I should be able to figure out the rest by myself now. :) THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your site.